# Not receiving Push Notifcations in DEBUG mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to resolve an issue with Push Notification in Xamarin.iOS but it seem that when I build in `Debug` mode onto a device, the push notifications are not received.

When I build the same code in `Ad-Hoc` mode onto the same device, the notifications come through. This poses an issue as I need to see which methods are being hit in the `AppDelegate`.

How can I achieve this? Is there some sort of configuration issue that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that it was a silly configuration issue on my part. You need to have a `Sandbox` APNS certificate from the Developer Centre and upload that certificate in `Sandbox` mode to Azure.

Answer (score 2):

edit Entitlements.plist add

```
<dict>
  <key>aps-environment</key>
  <string>development</string>
</dict>
```